# Passing the salt along with hashed security key in URL

Tags: web-services, security, authentication, salt

So I'm trying to authenticate against a third party web app. The documentation with this third party web app suggest taking the our security key provided by the third party web app and hashing it with salt. They then want us to pass the generated salt along with the hashed security key which becomes known as the secret in the URL. My understanding is the third party web app would then use the security key and hash it with the salt provided in the URL to see if it matches the secret passed along in the URL. This seems like a major security risk. Could someone explain why this would or would not be a security risk?

Doc
http://wiki.kayako.com/display/DEV/Kayako+REST+API

Sample Request

```
https://example.domain.com/api/index.php
 ?e=/Module/Controller/Action
 &parameterA=valueA
 &parameterB=valueB
 &parameterC=valueC
 &apikey=d75a00ef-08b6-5b04-5d29-d3b7ca46138a
 &salt=itobgt701t5nat7oor9z4t813edc5t8d
 &signature=MzNiNjk4ZmUyY2FlNjQ5YmRkNjA0YjkyYTQ0NmY5OTQ4MGVkYTIwMzZjMzFkYmJjMzk4MzgzNjNiMzZjYTE4NQ==
```

Comment: The security risk would be for man-in-the-middle attacks, wherein a third party could grab the SALT and SIGNATURE values to create forged requests. That's why the docs you listed stress the importance of randomizing the SALT. However, provided the connection is made through HTTPS, MITM attacks are much more difficult.

Comment: @DavidW guess my thought was what stops the man in the middle from just using the generated url a second time to gain access? I mean if they already have the hashed secret along with the salt, what stops them from just using it? Do you lock down access from the third party service so that it only allows access from a particular domain? Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Origin domain checking is one avenue, also detection of duplicate SALT values on the inbound side, but keep in mind, too, that https up front makes MITM *very* difficult.